# BluetoothAuthenticateDevice returns BTH_ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE

Tags: c++, bluetooth, windows-10

After a long while of troubleshooting this problem I can't find out what is causing it. Everytime I run my program the BluetoothAuthenticateDevice function returns BTH_ERROR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE

I tried running it as admin even though I am the only user and admin, looking at the bthserv service, reinstalling drivers and some other small things but it didn't work. I don't want to reinstall Windows because it will be a lot of work to get my system back up and running and because this is my main computer

The program is working on my work- and home laptop (Both Windows 10 laptops) but not my main computer. Bluetooth is working fine when used normally but my program does not work.  [Here is a picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzZ7R.png)

[The code can be found here](https://github.com/StarlightNL/WiimoteLib/tree/QuickPushBranch/WiiPair)

I hope someone can help me with this problem.